# Streaming endless custom audio bytes in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, audio, just-audio

Using the just_audio API on Windows 10 building a windows app, I'm trying to create a `StreamAudioSource` that streams audio as 16bit PCM wav from a synthesizer running via dart:ffi (in this case, just a basic oscillator). Full code in [repo](https://github.com/t2techno/flutter_faust_ffi).

TLDR: My class extends `StreamAudioSource`, the stream parameter for the `StreamAudioResponse` in the overridden `StreamAudioSource.request()` method is given a `Stream.periodic()` object. When playing the `audioPlayer` that consumes my custom `StreamAudioSource`, I receive the following exception:

```
"HttpException: Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 1088 bytes written while expected 544."
```

I have confirmed that my wav header is working properly and that I can write a playable `.wav` file.

Some relevant constants: `_sampleRate: 48000, _bufferSize=125, _bitRate=16, _numChannels=2`.
My Stream of audio, when listened to, is producing data in batches of 544 Bytes (125samples * 2channels * 2Bytes + 44Byte header) as expected. Which makes the exception of exactly double suspicious.

My synth class, which interfaces with the C API and produces the actual audio bytes as a Uint8List, extends the `StreamAudioSource`. I am creating and keeping references to a `Stream.periodic()` stream  and it's `streamSubscription`:

```
void initializeStream(){
    _synthStream = Stream<Uint8List>.periodic(_tick, 
        (count) => _waveFile.headerWithData(compute())
    ).asBroadcastStream();

    // pause the stream until we need it
    // when I print data.length in listener, it is 544Bytes as expected
    _streamSub = _synthStream.listen((data)=>{})..pause();
}

// isPcm == true
Uint8List compute() {
    _impl.computemydsp(_mydsp, _bufferSize, _inputBuffer, _buffer);
    return _isPcm ? interleavedIntBytes : interleavedFloatBytes;
}
// should run about 48000/125 = 384 times per second
_tick = Duration(microseconds:(1000000*bufferSize)~/_sampleRate);

Uint8List get interleavedIntBytes {
    Float32List left  = leftFloats;
    Float32List right = rightFloats;
    for(var i=0; i<_bufferSize; i++){
        _bb..add(int16bytes((left[i]* signedInt16Max).toInt()))
           ..add(int16bytes((right[i]*signedInt16Max).toInt()));
    }
    return _bb.takeBytes();
}

// _buffer = Pointer<Pointer<Float>>
Float32List get leftFloats  => _buffer[0].asTypedList(_bufferSize);
Float32List get rightFloats => _buffer[1].asTypedList(_bufferSize);

Uint8List int16bytes(int v) => Uint8List(2)..buffer.asInt16List()[0] = v
```

I'm using the `_synthStream` as the parameter in the `StreamAudioResponse` object returned from the overridden `StreamAudioSource.request()` method:

```
@override
Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    print('request');
    _streamSub.resume();

    start ??= 0;
    end ??= _batchByteSize;
    print('end: $end');
    return StreamAudioResponse(
        sourceLength: 10000000,
        contentLength: end - start,
        offset: start,
        stream: _synthStream,
        contentType: 'audio/wave',
    );
}
```

Note: The `sourceLength` was set to an arbitrarily large number while I tried to get the stream to work. If I naively increase the `contentLength` to 1088, `_batchByteSize*2`, then the exceeded size becomes 1632, which is again, one batch larger than what I specified.

This seems like it would either be an issue with my use of streams or the way I am providing it to the `StreamAudioResponse`. Because the player is receiving a larger amount of data than I specify, I imagine my problem has to do with where I add my wave header to the audio stream, and how I can get the content size for the stream to be used in the `StreamAudioResponse` object.

WaveFile:

```
Uint8List headerWithData(Uint8List data){
    // ToDo: poor error handling
    if (_header.lengthInBytes == 0){
        print('need to initialize header first');
        return data;
    }

    if(_subchunk2Size == data.length){
        // BytesBuilder
        _output..add(headerBytes)..add(data);
        return _output.takeBytes();
    }
    
    _subchunk2Size = data.length;
    updateNBytesForOffset(4, fourBytes(_subchunk2Size), _subchunk2SizeOffset);

    _chunkSize = (_wavHeaderSize-8) + _subchunk2Size;
    updateNBytesForOffset(4, fourBytes(_chunkSize), _chunkSizeOffset);
    _output..add(headerBytes)..add(data);
    return _output.takeBytes();
}

void updateNBytesForOffset(int n, Uint8List bytes, int offset){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        offset+=i;
        _header.setUint8(offset, bytes[i]);
    }
}

Uint8List fourBytes(int v) => Uint8List(4)..buffer.asByteData().setInt32(0,v,Endian.little);
```

Comment: It's years old and only for iOS and Android, but consider adapting https://github.com/richardheap/audio_worklet which was built for a talk on Flutter plugins. It gives a much simpler, demand-based callback - you get asked for the next set of samples when the sound card is ready for them. It pre-dates support for Float32List, which would have avoided a bunch of conversions from float<->double. No need for headers (there's just one format), but you'd need to implement stereo. On the callback, you could call your synth and return the floats.

Comment: First side note would be to set `sourceLength` to `null` if the total length is unknown, and this will translate to a `*` appearing in the header. But the error isn't related to that, it's related to your stream outputting more bytes than the number you indicated in `contentLength`. So you need to ensure that the stream you pass into `stream: ...` only emits `end - start` bytes, whereas your stream is outputting more than that. This stream shouldn't be a stream that gradually outputs the whole file, it should be a stream that *only* outputs the sub-range that was requested, i.e. `start:end`.